# AWS API Gateway Caching by Query Parameter not working

Tags: amazon-web-services, caching, aws-lambda, aws-api-gateway

This is question is slightly different than [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48886715/aws-api-gateway-caching-ignores-query-parameters), but related. I have AWS API gateway setup with a single `GET` method, which has 1 query parameter `search`. This `GET` call returns a list of words based on the search string. I have turned on caching by this query parameter, but get the same results, no matter the query parameter. When I turn caching off, it works as expected.

1. First request `search=a*` => words that start with `a` are returned, as expected
2. Second request `search=b*` => words that start with `a` are returned, but I expect words that start with `b`.

Why aren't my requests being cached by the query parameter?

API Settings:
[image: API Cache Settings]

Method Query Parameter:
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It might help if I actually [deployed](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/how-to-deploy-api-with-console.html) the API after making the changes.